# Is there any way to know whether referring to to non existing actor in akka

Tags: java, akka

I am trying to post messages to some existing actors like show below but there may be a chance to to refer non existing actor and i would like to know before posting the message.
Thanks in advance

```
actor = getContext().actorFor("actorSystem/user/" + nameOfActor);
actor.tell("message",getSelf());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is snippet of my code how i implemented used DeadLettersHandler actor to handle DeadLetters

```
public class MyActor extends UntypedActor
{
 @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception 
  {
     System.out.println("MyActor received : "+message.toString());
  }
}

public class DeadLettersHandler extends UntypedActor
{
  public void onReceive(Object deadLetter) throws Exception
  {
   System.out.println("DeadLettersHandler received : "+deadLetter.toString());
  }
}


public class DeadLetterTest 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     ActorSystem MyActorSystem = ActorSystem.create("MyActorSystem");
     ActorRef existingActor = MyActorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class),"ExistingActor");
     ActorRef DLH = MyActorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(DeadLettersHandler.class), "DeadLetterHandler");
     MyActorSystem.eventStream().subscribe(DLH, DeadLetter.class);
     ActorSelection nonExist = MyActorSystem.actorSelection("akka://user/MyActorSystem/NonExistingActor");
     existingActor.tell("Hello Akka", existingActor);
     nonExist.tell("Hello Akka", DLH);
     MyActorSystem.shutdown();
    }
}

 output:

 MyActor received : Hello Akka
 DeadLettersHandler received : DeadLetter(Hello Akka,Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/user/DeadLetterHandler#-3707992],Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/deadLetters])
 [INFO] [10/10/2013 15:43:43.343] [MyActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://MyActorSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/user/DeadLetterHandler#-3707992] to Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send them Identify message prior to sending your actual message. All actors understand it and should reply with `Self()`. Alternatively use `resolveOne` method:

> You can acquire an ActorRef for an ActorSelection with the
>   resolveOne method of the ActorSelection. It returns a Future of the
>   matching ActorRef if such an actor exists. It is completed with
>   failure [[akka.actor.ActorNotFound]] if no such actor exists or the
>   identification didn't complete within the supplied timeout.

Comment: Using the `Identify` message is tricky. Since `Identify` is a normal message it will be added to the actor's queue like all the other messages. If the actor is busy, the `Self` message may be sent at a much later time, thus causing a timeout and creating the false impression that the actor doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way of knowing that an actor is alive (without DeathWatch) is by receiving a message from it. And that only proves that the actor was alive at some point in time (when it has sent the message).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I need to handle the every message received, if a actor not exists then that message has to be handled separately which i achied using Deadletter implementation

```
final ActorRef actor = actorSystem.actorOf(new Props(DeadLetterHandlerActor.class));
actorSystem.eventStream().subscribe(actor, DeadLetter.class);
```